# ARM template deployment effect on already running MemSQL Instance

Tags: ansible, azure-devops, singlestore

I have an ARM template to deploy all of my resources as the production setup. Initially when I used to deploy the resources through the ARM template, everything was fine and our setup is up and running. We did started a MemSQL cluster into the setup. We have an application running using the MemSQL cluster. Now, we have some changes to the setup, specifically to the Ubuntu VMs, where MemSQL is running, like adding disks, assigning private IP etc.

The question what I have here is, **does any changes made through the ARM deployment, effects the, in memory data for the running application on the VMs, specifically the MemSQL data?**

Answer (score 0):

the answer is - it depends. it wouldn't delete any data (unless you are using complete deployment mode). but it might (depending on what you are doing) detach data disks, or reboot the vms (if you change the sku, for example), if you change private ip addresses cluster might fall apart, as the nodes won't be able to talk to each other, etc.

I'd recommend having a dev cluster where you test your ARM templates and then you can apply the changes to the prod cluster

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41 for the helpful reply. We have started the application thinking, never to stop or reboot any of the instances in near multiple years. And we might not change the IP as well. But yes we might attach or detach the disks(in case of disk failure), and that is where our concern is, that since ARM deployment touches everything mentioned in the template, so does it refresh or reload the resources and its value or data? If it reloads or refresh the MemSQL, we might lose something which we don't want, but still I am not sure what that could be.

Comment: sorry, but that's not how you design a cloud application :) disk failure is impossible on Azure as well (well, impossible might be too strong of a word, but certainly not something you would expect to happen). ARM deployment would update resources. what that would do to a resource depends on what you are changing in the resource properties and what that resource is. there is no way to give a generalized answer about this. One thing though, ARM templates do not do what you don't instruct them to do and if you dont have script extension assined to the VM they wont do anything INSIDE the VM.